# How to fix indentation? Haskell: parse error on input `|'

Tags: haskell

So I am getting the error:

```
error:
parse error on input `|'

   | x == 'a' = True
```

The code itself is:

```
module SubstitutionCiphers where
import AssignmentHelp.Cipher

validateCipher ::  Cipher -> Boolean
  validateCipher "" = False
  validateCipher (x:xs) 
    | x == 'a' = True
    | otherwise = validateCipher xs
```

I tried alternating the indentation in various different ways but nothing seems to work. I guess it is still an indentation problem, but I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Please do *not* indent the part under the signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you indent the first line of the definition, the parser (in this context) thinks you are continuing the previous line, as if you had written

```
validateCipher :: Cipher -> Bool validateCipher "" = False -- etc
```

This becomes obvious with a simpler definition

```
validateCipher :: String -> Bool
  validateCipher _ = True
```

because the parser is able to accept this. The resulting placement of the type signature, though, is invalid.

```
<interactive>:11:1: error:
    Illegal type signature: ‘String -> Bool validateCipher _’
      Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables
```

(I suspect that, if the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension did not exist, you would get a more generic parser error on the `=`. )

In your actual definition, the parser continues trying to parse a type signature, and doesn't run into a *syntactic* problem until it sees the `|`.

The solution is to not indent the definition:

```
validateCipher ::  Cipher -> Bool
validateCipher "" = False
validateCipher (x:xs) 
  | x == 'a' = True
  | otherwise = validateCipher xs
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not indent the part below the signature. Just write this as:

```
validateCipher ::  Cipher -> Bool
validateCipher "" = False
validateCipher (x:xs)
    | x == 'a' = True
    | otherwise = validateCipher xs
```

or you can just check this with:

```
validateCipher :: Cipher -> Bool
validateCipher = elem 'a'
```